# Loading a CSV file in D3

Tags: d3.js

There is problem in d3 while loading a csv file. It gives me following errors 1) GET http://d3js.org/d3.v.min.js 
2)Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
    (anonymous function)

> ```
> <head>
> <title>D3 total practice </title>
>  <script src ="http://d3js.org/d3.v.min.js"> </script>
>
> </head>
> <body>
> <script>
> d3.csv("sampath.csv",function(data1)
> {      
>
> }
> );
> </script>
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a typo in your d3 call. It should be:

```
<script src ="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"> </script>
```